# react-hook-form How to access the RegisterOptions that is passed in the `register()` inside the input component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

So in react-hook-forms you can define a custom field/input using:

```
const MyInput = React.forwardRef(({ name, label, ...rest }, ref) => {
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input name={name} placeholder="Jane" {...rest} ref={ref} />
    </>
  );
});
```

then to use it, we pass a `register()` function with the options/object:

```
<div>
    <MyInput
        name="firstName"
        label="First Name"
        {...register("firstName", {required: "This is required"})}
                                    ^
                                    |
                                    +-- how to access this object?
    />
</div>
```

my question is, how to access the `RegisterOptions` that was used to instantiate the input via the `register()` function?

the reason for this is because I want to check if the input was instantiated as "required"

atm, I have to do a non-DRY approach where I passed another `required` prop to the custom input:

```
<div>
    <MyInput
        name="firstName"
        label="First Name"
        {...register("firstName", {required: "This is required"})}
        required={true}             ^
              ^                     |
              |                     |
              +---------------------+-- redundant, how to avoid?
    />
</div>
```

then inside my custom input, I will read the `required` props, which is non-DRY, i have to define the `required` detail twice.
Is there a way I can just read what options are passed to the `register()` function inside the input?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is metadata held by the library. Even if you can access it via the form context (I'm not sure) that would be very unergonomic.

In this sort of situation, it makes sense to build out your own abstraction on top of `register`. This kind of wrapper layer around form libs is quite common.

```
const useRegister = () => {
    const { register } = useForm();
    return useCallback((...args) => {
        const [, metadata] = args
        return { ...register(...args), ...(metadata.required ? { required: true } : {}) }
    }, [register])
}
```

If you wanted you could also create a `useForm` wrapper that consumes this and returns your register instead of the vanilla one.

Comment: Thanks @adsy I ended up passing the whole RegisterOption to the custom Input component and reading the passed props there.